# Linq syntax to compare two lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of custom type objects

```
List<Obj> list1;
List<Obj> list2;

class Obj
{
  public List<X> xlist;
  public List<Y> Ylist;
  public bool mybool;

}

class X
{
   int x;
   float y;

}


class Y
{
   sting str;
   bool  y;

}
```

I want to compare that each member in list1 and list2 have equal values.Is it possible to do it in LINQ.

Comment: You want to know if all `xlist` items in `list1` equal all `xlist` items in `list2` and the same for `Ylist`? Or do you also want to compere the `Obj` itself. However, does the order matter?

Comment: Just my opinion, but don't be so obsessed with LINQ. LINQ exists to save you time. If the time it takes you to figure out how to write a LINQ query is longer than the time it takes to write the equivalent loop, then you should just write the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` meaningfully. You could also implement `IEquatable<Obj>` or use a custom `IEqualityComparer<Obj>` for LINQ methods like `SequenceEqual` or `Except`. For example:

```
public class Obj:  IEquatable<Obj>
{
    public List<X> xlist;
    public List<Y> Ylist;
    public bool mybool;


    public bool Equals(Obj other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        if (mybool != other.mybool) return false;
        return xlist.SequenceEqual(other.xlist) && Ylist.SequenceEqual(other.Ylist);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = mybool ? 13 : 19;
            foreach (X x in xlist)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + x.GetHashCode();
            }
            foreach (Y y in Ylist)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + y.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}

public class X: IEquatable<X>
{
    public int x;
    public float y;

    public bool Equals(X other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;

    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as X;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return this.Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 19;
            hash = hash * 31 + x;
            hash = hash * 31 + (int)y;
            return hash;
        }
    }
}


public class Y : IEquatable<Y>
{
    public string str;
    public bool y;

    public bool Equals(Y other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return str == other.str && y == other.y;

    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Y;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return this.Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 19;
            hash = hash * 31 + (str == null ? 0 : str.GetHashCode());
            hash = hash * 31 + (y ? 1 : 0);
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you could use `SequenceEqual` for your `List<Obj>`:

```
bool sameItemsSameOrder = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);  // finally you got your one-liner
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the extension method [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). "Determines whether two sequences are equal by comparing the elements by using the default equality comparer for their type." with an overload with your own equality comparer.

```
var areEqual = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

By default, it calls the Equals method on the object in the list, so make sure that it does what you need or pass your own equality comparer.

Linq is a query syntax. You need Linq to e.g. find items in one list which are not in the other list. Comparing sequences with SequenceEqual is not a query and IMHO not really Linq. However, does it matter?